# Dashboard Component HTML Rendering

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I am having dashboard component with 16 sub components on single page.

Each of those component will be having their data to display based on API call.

My query is how to wait for all the data to be loaded and then display the page or follow an alternative approach to show spinner in each sub component or in dashboard page.

Some component will have data from Twitter and Facebook feed.

So overall I have no idea about when all of the data will be present.

Should i create dashboard service for all the 16 sub component and use State Resolver for the service.

Kindly suggest some ideas which I can implement.

Comment: The best solution would be to implement incremental approach that means just fire the API from each component onInit and then put spinner for each component, so that user should not wait for all the components and their data to load to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Using Resolver is a good way to accomplish that, here's an exemple:
Create a new script ts with contact.resolve.ts name and fill in the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class ContactResolve implements Resolve<any> {
 constructor(private  dataservice: ContactService){}
 resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        state:RouterStateSnapshot,
       ): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataservice.getContacts();  
  }
}
```

Add the resolve parameter to the angular routing like the following code.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactListComponent } from './contact-list/contact-list.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ContactDetailComponent } from './contact-detail/contact-detail.component';
import { ContactResolve } from './contact.resolve';
import { DetailResolve } from './detail.resolve';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'contact', 
    component: ContactListComponent,
    resolve: {
      contact: ContactResolve,
    }},
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  { 
    path: 'contact-detail',
    component: ContactDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      detail: DetailResolve,
    }
  }
];
```

source : https://seegatesite.com/how-to-load-all-data-before-rendering-view-component-in-angular-4/